# Send ajax POST request to restfull api

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rest, cross-domain

I create an php slim framework based API by tutorial an now i'm able to register,login user with autentification:

```
URL     /register
Method  POST
Params  name, email, password
```

/register call dont need autentification so I write ajax to test API:

```
<button id="createPin"></button>
<script>
$(function() { 
    $('#createPin').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();


        var dataTest = { "name": "test", "email": "pepe@peperoni.com", "password": "sarasa" }
var urlAjax = "http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register";

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: urlAjax,
contentType: "application/json",
data: dataTest ,
success: function(data) { alert("ajax worked"); },
error: function(data) {console.log(data); },
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        },
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
});


}); 
});
</script>
```

I try to run this ajax call from localhost to agroagro.com/test/v1/register but I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Is there any solution to make cross-domain ajax request becouse I have a plan to use this code as frontend of an mobile app, so I need to make requests via ajax cross-domain...

*(restApi was created by following this tutorial:http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/)*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I read this but I dont know how I can implement this into my code... also I try this with chrom browser

Comment: you need to set the a-c-a-o header at the webserver that's serving up the JS code in question. If any arbitrary JS code could set the header, then there'd be no point in having the cross-origin restrictions. "Why, yes, I'm allowed to talk to whomevever I want". Nope. the server has to include the header "You are allowed to talk to X,Y,Z"

Comment: so I need on server side code to add: header with access-control...

Comment: yes. the server sends out your JS code, and includes the cors header to tell the browser that the js code is allowed to make requests to whatever site(s) you specify. "here's some code. it's allowed to make a CORS request to sites X, Y, and Z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the correct header responses.

In my case, I have a set of default header that I always set when I receive a call to my api controller. This is set in my _construct

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

There are some really helpful guide that will help you understand how CORS works and why you need it.

[Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

[Cross-domain Ajax with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

**EDIT:**

First you need to allow access to all origins by using Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *, you are doing this now so you will see a different error from the original one posted. I had a similar issue when using phoneGap and Ionic and it was solved by added the content-type header to my ajax call. This post helped me [XMLHttpRequest cannot load](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xyz-com-invalid-http-status-code-404-for-post-angular-js/3923).

I am using Codeigniter for my API so I don't know how much of this will help but it's very generic so should point you in the right direction.

I have a controller called API which is used to fetch data from a database and return JSON.

```
class Api extends CI_Controller {
    ....
    ....
}
```

In this class I have a __construct function. A __construct is always run when the class in called so you don't need to call it yourself. Within the __construct set the headers CORS headers.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // Set access header
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

    ....
    ....
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I will try now to see

Comment: Please show me your set file with _construct ... I was add this into index.php file

Comment: When I add this to my _conctruct:  public function __construct($items = array())
    {
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
        $this->replace($items);
    } I GET:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.agroagro.com/test/v1/register. Invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: any example, where is the file where I need to put this code?